# Trying to format user input(phone-numbers, zip codes) but am getting type error

Tags: python

I'm trying to format user input into #####-####. However, I'm getting a type error at the moment. "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". Any advice on how to proceed with this?
``

```
    user_input='0'
while re.fullmatch(r'\d{9}',user_input) is None:
    user_input = input("Please enter a valid zip code+4: \n")
user_input = [user_input]
result = re.fullmatch(r'(\d{5})(\d{4})',   user_input)
result='-'.join(r'(\d{5})(\d{4})')
print(result)
```

``

*****EDIT****
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dante\Python_Projects\PythonLab4.py", line 30, in 
Zip_Code()
File "C:\Users\Dante\Python_Projects\PythonLab4.py", line 22, in Zip_Code
result = re.fullmatch(r'(\d{5})(\d{4})',   user_input)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 196, in fullmatch
return _compile(pattern, flags).fullmatch(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: You've got to show us the ___complete___ error traceback, not just the last line …

Answer (score 1):

The error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` was passing the list to `re.fullmatch()`, but the AnyStr (str, bytes) type is required.  Remove the line `user_input = [user_input]` or use `user_input[0]` in `re.fullmatch()`.
But by correcting this error, you get `(-\-d-{-5-}-)-(-\-d-{-4-}-)`, not `12345-6789`. Try this code:

```
import re

user_input = '0'
while re.fullmatch(r'\d{9}', user_input) is None:
    user_input = input("Please enter a valid zip code+4: \n")
result = re.sub(r'(\d{5})(\d{4})', r"\1-\2", user_input)
print(result)
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you explain the r"\1-\2" part of your code? I'm looking at the syntax on the documentation side of things and would like to understand this part more so I can properly apply to this to other formats like phone numbers

Comment: [Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)